# Django populating dropdown with values

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hello guys i want to populate a dropdown with the ids from the database, but when iterating over the list i get back also the brackets and the commas and some spaces.

In views.py, i have the following:

```
id = list(Device.objects.values_list('patientId', flat=True).distinct())
print(id)
for item in id:
    print(item)

context = {"filename": filename,
           "collapse": "",
           "patientId": json.dumps(id),
           "labels": json.dumps(labels, default=str),
           "data": json.dumps(data),
           }
```

The print is returning exactly what i want the ids(1,2,3), but when going in the frontend(index.html), with the following code:

```
{{patientId}}
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="patientId">Choose a patient:</label>
                    <select name="patient" id="patient">
                        {% for item in patientId%}
                        <option value="{{item}}">
                                {{item}}
                        </option>
                        {%endfor%}
                    </select>
```

[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzkmU.png)

How can i get in the frontend the dropdown with the correct values?

Comment: I think your `endfor` should be like this `{% endfor %}` and your `for` loop should be like this `{% for item in patientId %}`. Try these, if it doesn't work, message me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you dont pass a `list` to the django template, instead you are passing a `str` (string representation of list -> json)

```
context = {"filename": filename,
           "collapse": "",
           "patientId": json.dumps(id), # < -----------------------
           "labels": json.dumps(labels, default=str),
           "data": json.dumps(data),
           }
```

that line should be

```py
   "patientId": id # this should be a better and more specific name
```

because you need to pass a list to the template in order to iterate over it like this

```
{% for item in patientId%}
```

and btw, you templates should look like this

```
{% for item in patientId %} # notice the space
{% endfor %} # notice the spaces
```